# take all row of cloumn selected in php

Tags: php

my table have 3 field :RapperName , MusicPath , MusicName

now in this function check that name exist or not i want in else statement
take all row of that cloumns i mean if for example row_count==5 take all rows of that cloumns

```
     public function TakeAll($name){

  $sql = 'SELECT * from Rap WHERE RapperName =:name';

  // find all column's with that name and take all column's with rows


  }
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` will *always* return *exactly* one row (unless you use GROUP BY or have a syntax error). one row containing *not* the data  you want, but the *amount of rows*. if you actually want the data, you have to `SELECT *`. (also: you should probably rename the column, variables and functions, because a "Raper" is something completely different from a "Rapper")

Comment: @user7415865 Don't change your question so frequently, which will make the answers irrelevant.

Comment: @Raptor why all people come here and tell me details ? if you can just answer my question else this conversations not help me

Answer (score 0):

use query

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from Rap WHERE RaperName =:name';
```

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer :

```
 public function TakeAll($name){


  $sql ="SELECT * from Rap WHERE RapperName={$name}";
  $result = mysql_fetch_all($conn, $sql);
    return $result;

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using some of PHP framework.
Try to use following PHP code using your framework syntax, this might help you to get an idea what exactly you require to do.

```
public function checkRaperExist($name){

  $sql = mysql_query("select * from Rap where RaperName = '".$name."'");

  $row_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    if($sql){

        if ($row_count < 0){
            return false;

        } else {
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                $data[] = $row;
            }            
            print_r($data); 
        }
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: **don't** use the deprecated `mysql`-functions - OP already used (probably) PDO. also: your code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection** - OP already used prepared statements. using your answer, OP would severely decrease his code quality in two different ways.